# VueJs POST with fetch not sending data to firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, vuejs3, fetch-api

I'm trying to send a POST request to a firebase cloud function from `Vue.js 3` but I can't seem to get the data to actually send.

Here is the code I am using to make the request

```
const requestOptions = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, gender: gender })
};

await fetch('...url/to/function/helloWorld', requestOptions)
    .then(async response => {
         const data = await response.json();
         console.log(data)
     }
})
```

In the cloud function I have:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cors(req, res, () => {

        const name = req.query.name
        const gender = req.query.gender

        functions.logger.log("Req: ", req.body.name);
        functions.logger.log("name: ", name);
        functions.logger.log("gender: ", gender);

        const response = {
            name: name,
            gender: gender
        }
        res.send(response)
    })
});
```

When I check the google firebase logs, I see this:

[image]

When I check the console log. I get `204` response.

I have added some dummy information into the body to check if it was the variables not been set like so:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ name: "name", gender:"gender" })
```

But that doesn't do anything either.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the full `index.js` file for the `cloud` function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// IMPORTANTO
// REMOVE CORS FROM THIS, ONLY USED FOR TESTING
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

        cors(req, res, () => {

            const name = req.body.name
            const gender = req.body.gender

            functions.logger.log("Req: ", req.body.name);
            functions.logger.log("name: ", name);
            functions.logger.log("gender: ", gender);

            const response = {
                name: name,
                gender: gender
            }
            res.send(response)
        })
});
```

EDIT: Payload information.

The function is called 2 times in the console.

1 with status `200` and `fetch`
2 with status `204` and `preflight`

The one with 200 has no payload. The one with 204 has the following:

[image]

Comment: @Phil I also used req.body as you can see.

Comment: @phil - I also tried it with hard coded values as I mentioned lower in the post.

Comment: @Phil no worries, thank you for responding anyway. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I only added `const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });` at the stop of my cloud function.

Comment: ok, done that now.

Comment: Check your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel. Does the request payload look correct? You should presumably see two requests, one `OPTIONS` and one `POST`. Only the latter should have a request body but do they both receive successful responses?

Comment: Can you add the firebase log after you made the change from `req.query` to `req.body` and also a screenshot of your network tab in browser devtools?

Comment: I have added the output from the console into the main post

Comment: @Phil - sorry I am not sure what you mean. I cant see `payload` anywhere. Across the top are just headers, preview, response, initiator, timer - both preview and response are empty

Comment: In Chrome it's under the headers I think (scroll down to the bottom). In Firefox it's in the _Request_ tab

Comment: @Phil sorry for the delay, I didnt have it as I was not using chrome.. just installed it now and got what you needed.